# Viewport limited view of my objects

Tags: 3d-view

I pressed a hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> I think and now can only see this much of my objects.

If I go into *Look Dev* I can see all of my object, but no longer in sub-object mode.  I cannot undo or figure out what happened.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please disregard the overlapping mesh. editing an imported FBX that I created in Max.  Blender user since 2009.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It's not really clear from those screenshots, would you mind [sharing your .blend file?](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)